# Kubernetes private registry certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, docker-registry

I'm using a bitnami kubernetes image on a AWS EC2 Instance.

kubectl cluster-info says

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.30.0.120:6443
Heapster is running at https://172.30.0.120:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://172.30.0.120:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
monitoring-grafana is running at https://172.30.0.120:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy
monitoring-influxdb is running at https://172.30.0.120:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb/proxy
```

so I'm asuming i only have a master and no node?

I deployed a private registry via

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: registry
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: registry
        id: "registry"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: registry
        image: registry:2.7.0
        ports:
        - name: registry-port
          containerPort: 5000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/registry
          name: images
        - mountPath: /certs
          name: certs
        - mountPath: /auth
          name: auth
        env:
        - name: REGISTRY_AUTH
          value: "htpasswd"
        - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM
          value: "Registry Realm"
        - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH
          value: /auth/htpasswd
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
          value: /certs/domain.crt
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
          value: /certs/domain.key
      volumes:
      - name: images
        hostPath:
          path: /home/bitnami/registry/images
      - name: certs
        hostPath:
          path: /home/bitnami/docker_reg_certs
      - name: auth
        hostPath:
          path: /home/bitnami/registry/auth
```

I generate a self-signed ssl-ca via openssl and copied it to /etc/docker/certs.d/[ec2-insta-domain:port] and to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt and do update-ca-certificates and sudo service docker restart.
After that i login to my registry with docker login [domainname]:5000 and enter user and pw. This work.
Then i create a docker-registry secret with kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=~/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

After that i create my deployment

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: app-config-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-config-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-config-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-config-service
        image: [AWS-EC2-DomainName]:5000/cloud/app-config-service:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 48000
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILE
          value: docker
        - name: SPRING_BOOT_PORT
          value: "48000"
        - name: KAFKA_BINDER_BROKERS_URL
          value: xxxxxxxxxxx:29095
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-secret
```

But when i try to run this deployment with kubectl create -f deployment.yml and describe the created pod i get the error failed to do request: Head https://[domainname]:5000/v2/cloud/app-config-service/manifests/latest: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

The log of the registry says 2020/07/14 15:54:01 http: TLS handshake error from 10.32.0.1:37943: remote error: tls: bad certificate

If i try to connect manually to the private repositry with curl -X GET https://[domainname]:5000/v2/_catalog it works.

Anyone know what i'm missing or doing wrong here?

Greetings

EDIT

I found out something interesting. For my kubernetes i use the container runtime containerd github.com/containerd/containerd v1.3.3 d76c121f76a5fc8a462dc64594aea72fe18e1178

I edit the /etc/containered/config.toml like this

```
version = 2
root = "/var/lib/containerd"
state = "/run/containerd"
plugin_dir = ""
disabled_plugins = []
required_plugins = []
oom_score = 0

[grpc]
  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
  tcp_address = ""
  tcp_tls_cert = ""
  tcp_tls_key = ""
  uid = 0
  gid = 0
  max_recv_message_size = 16777216
  max_send_message_size = 16777216

[ttrpc]
  address = ""
  uid = 0
  gid = 0

[debug]
  address = ""
  uid = 0
  gid = 0
  level = ""

[metrics]
  address = ""
  grpc_histogram = false

[cgroup]
  path = ""

[timeouts]
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.cleanup" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.load" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.shutdown" = "3s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.task.state" = "2s"

[plugins]
  [plugins."io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"]
    pause_threshold = 0.02
    deletion_threshold = 0
    mutation_threshold = 100
    schedule_delay = "0s"
    startup_delay = "100ms"
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
    disable_tcp_service = true
    stream_server_address = "127.0.0.1"
    stream_server_port = "0"
    stream_idle_timeout = "4h0m0s"
    enable_selinux = false
    sandbox_image = "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1"
    stats_collect_period = 10
    systemd_cgroup = false
    enable_tls_streaming = false
    max_container_log_line_size = 16384
    disable_cgroup = false
    disable_apparmor = false
    restrict_oom_score_adj = false
    max_concurrent_downloads = 3
    disable_proc_mount = false
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd]
      snapshotter = "overlayfs"
      default_runtime_name = "runc"
      no_pivot = false
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime]
        runtime_type = ""
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime]
        runtime_type = ""
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v1"
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/opt/cni/bin"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
      max_conf_num = 1
      conf_template = ""
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.va.cri".registry.mirrors."ip:5000"]
        endpoint = ["http://ip:5000"]
        [plugins."io.containerd.gprc.v1.cri".registry.auths]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.va.cri".registry.mirrors."172.30.0.120:5000"]
        endpoint = ["http://172.30.0.120:5000"]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.va.cri".registry.mirrors."domainname:5000"]
        endpoint = ["http://domainame:5000"]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
        endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
    [plugins."io.containerd.gprc.v1.cri".registry.auths."http://ip:5000"]
      username = "admin"
      password = "admin"
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".x509_key_pair_streaming]
      tls_cert_file = ""
      tls_key_file = ""
  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"]
    path = "/opt/containerd"
  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"]
    interval = "10s"
  [plugins."io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"]
    content_sharing_policy = "shared"
  [plugins."io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"]
    no_prometheus = false
  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"]
    shim = "containerd-shim"
    runtime = "runc"
    runtime_root = ""
    no_shim = false
    shim_debug = false
  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"]
    platforms = ["linux/amd64"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"]
    default = ["walking"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"]
    root_path = ""
    pool_name = ""
    base_image_size = ""
```

but if i call crictl info the output show me the following

```
...
...
 },
    "registry": {
      "mirrors": {
        "docker.io": {
          "endpoint": [
            "https://registry-1.docker.io"
          ]
        }
      },
...
...
```

So the `config.toml` has no effect of the used registry of my kubernetes? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide ~/.docker/config.json file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you created the secret `my-secret` in default namespace but the deployment `app-config-service` is running in `kube-system` namespace and hence can not refer to `my-secret` using `imagePullSecrets`. Creating the secret `my-secret` in `kube-system` namespace should solve the issue.